# How to disable Mobile verification after creation of new user using Google Directory API

Tags: mobile, gmail, verification, google-directory-api, google-apps-for-education

To create new users i am using Google Directory API in my .net web application. Its working fine at the time of creation. But after creation of new user when I login to mail with new user its asking for **Verify your identity**.

In that window it’s asking for mobile number verification through text message or Voice call. How can i skip this verification? I already unchecked 2-step verification check box in admin console.
In real time scenario all students may not have mobile numbers.

Answer (score -1):

If you set your domain's company profile to one of the education sector options you should avoid 2FV.

1. Verify that 2FV if disabled:

   - Admin console > Security > Basic settings > Two-step verification
2. Ensure that your Company Profile for your domain is "education":

   - Admin console > Company profile > Organisation type

We had a similar problem in our GAFE domain & while we had done step 1, it was step 2 that ensured that this was honoured.